# Возникает ошибка при возвращении в приложение

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, livedata

Используется `Activity`, `Fragment`, `ViewModel`, `LiveData`, `Dagger2`.

Открываю фрагмент на которой отображается карта и маркеры. Все работает хорошо. Сворачиваю/разворачиваю - все прекрасно.

Пробовал полность убрать все фрагменты, Остается только Main Activity, в который даггер инжектит поля(в том числе ViewModel) в методе init ViewModel`а выполняются действия и больше там ничего не выполняется.

Но, если ждать выключения экрана то при разблокировке экранапроисходит фатальная ошибка. Кто нибудь сталкивался с таким? Что может быть?

```
    2020-07-15 15:26:05.069 11643-12450/ru.mydomain.product D/FA: Connected to remote service 
2020-07-15 15:26:06.944 11643-12450/ru.mydomain.product D/FA: Application going to the background 
2020-07-15 15:28:42.267 11643-11643/ru.mydomain.product D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM 
2020-07-15 15:28:42.270 11643-11643/ru.mydomain.product E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: ru.mydomain.product, PID: 6075
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to call observer method
            at androidx.lifecycle.ClassesInfoCache$MethodReference.invokeCallback(ClassesInfoCache.java:226)
            at androidx.lifecycle.ClassesInfoCache$CallbackInfo.invokeMethodsForEvent(ClassesInfoCache.java:194)
            at androidx.lifecycle.ClassesInfoCache$CallbackInfo.invokeCallbacks(ClassesInfoCache.java:185)
            at androidx.lifecycle.ReflectiveGenericLifecycleObserver.onStateChanged(ReflectiveGenericLifecycleObserver.java:37)
            at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:361)
            at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.forwardPass(LifecycleRegistry.java:300)
            at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.sync(LifecycleRegistry.java:339)
            at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.moveToState(LifecycleRegistry.java:145)
            at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.handleLifecycleEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:131)
            at androidx.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleOwner.activityStarted(ProcessLifecycleOwner.java:111)
            at androidx.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleOwner$2.onStart(ProcessLifecycleOwner.java:82)
            at androidx.lifecycle.ReportFragment.dispatchStart(ReportFragment.java:88)
            at androidx.lifecycle.ReportFragment.onStart(ReportFragment.java:108)
            at android.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:2548)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1334)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1576)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1637)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchMoveToState(FragmentManager.java:3046)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStart(FragmentManager.java:3003)
            at android.app.FragmentController.dispatchStart(FragmentController.java:193)
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7165)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:2949)
            at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:180)
            at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:165)
            at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:142)
            at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1818)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6762)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

UP: Ошибка плавающая и непонятно почему возникает.

Comment: А Вы в `ViewModel::onCleared` что делаете?

Comment: compositeDisposable.dispose(). Этот метод вроде и не вызывается, хотя я не логиповал..

Comment: А у Вас есть возможность залить минимально воспроизводящий проблему код в гит? Было бы интересно попробовать разобраться.

Comment: Попробую на чистом проекте сымитировать, завтра. потом отпишусь

Comment: Сейчас решил попробовать воспроизвести ошибку, не получилось. т.е при дебаге(имею ввиду когда телефон был подключен к компу) ошибка воспроизводилась, а сейчас когда телефон не подключен по USB вроде все нормально (возможно это только совпадение).

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте в xml

```
android:text="@{String.valueOf(viewmodel.item.name)}
```

Comment: databinding не используется. тут дело в чем то другом

Answer (score 0):

Рискну предположить, что данное поведение может быть вызвано активированной настройкой режима разработчика "Вытеснение фоновых Activity". Если настройка не активирована, то попробуйте в режиме отладки убрать все break points и посмотреть воспроизводится ли ошибка. Возможно это связано с остановкой флоу выполнения программы.

Comment: нее, данная функция отключена. 
break point тоже ни при чем